# angular2 how to call method of object

Tags: forms, methods, angular

I have an model in which I have a method is valid

```
export class ModelClass{
   id: number;
   text : String,

   isValid() : boolean {
      return true;
}
}
```

a second model

```
export class Rows{
   editable: boolean;
   modelClass: ModelClass;
}
```

how to call it in html ???

```
<table border="1p;">

  <tbody >
    <tr *ngFor="let link of modelClassRows">
      <td>
         <div>toto {{link.applicationLink.isValid()}}</div>
      </td>
   </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

a part of my component where object are initialized

```
export class ApplicationLinkListComponent implements OnInit {

modelClassRows: Rows[] = new Array<Rows>();

constructor() {
  }

ngOnInit() {
   // fill modelClassRows
.....
}
```

Comment: I made [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pMUZWRHQdCXOJNBgV9YF?p=preview), check if it's what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate the `ModelClass` class this way:

```
let row = new Rows();
row.modelClass = new ModelClass();
row.modelClass.id = 'some id';
row.modelClass.title = 'some title';
modelClassRows.push(row);
```

If you instantiate it literally and cast it to the type, you won't be able to use the method.

For example:

```
let row = new Rows();
row.modelClass = <ModelClass>{
  id: 'some id',
  title: 'some title'
};
modelClassRows.push(row);
```